# Spring Boot Maven Plugin not creating executable jar

Tags: spring, maven-3, spring-boot

My POM is as below. But the executable JAR is not being create when I run "mvn clean package". However, when I remove the dependencyManagement element and add spring boot as parent  POM, everything works.

What am I missing?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>sample-boot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.0.M2</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 31):

You need to configure spring-boot-maven-plugin by yourself:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.8.RELEASE</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Obviously set your own plugin version. Now if you run mvn install or mvn package you'll have executable JAR generated.

Answer (score 6):

That's because the plugin is configured in the parent in the second case. If you want to manage your own plugins (ie not use the parent), you have to explicitly configure the spring boot plugin (and others).

Answer (score 2):

When you using Spring boot dependency management (without spring-boot-starter-parent) you can still keep the benefit of the dependency management, but **not the plugin management**.

That means that you need to provide full plugin (with version and other stuff).

Comment: Do you have a link to documentation that confirms this?

Comment: [Yes](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html#using-boot-maven-without-a-parent)

Comment: This resolved my error. I had `spring-boot-maven-plugin` inside of `<pluginManagement>` while also having some dependencies in `<dependencyManagement>`. Even with `<goal>repackage</goal>` specified on the plugin, I still wasn't getting an executable jar. Moving `spring-boot-maven-plugin` back into `<plugins>`  allowed me to get an executable jar again

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot will make sure your application will boot as a test when you run `mvn package`. Make sure it is not failing during this.

Answer (score 0):

> Given is **pom.xml** to create an executable jar file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.executablejar</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>demo Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <java-version>1.8</java-version>
    <docker.image.prefix>springDemo</docker.image.prefix>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>demo</finalName>
</build>
```

> To create executable jar, type following command

```
$ mvn clean
$ mvn install
```

> **Watch video :** https://youtu.be/Yy8RxjdcTfE

Answer (score 0):

According SpringBoot Document.
The plugin rewrites your manifest, and in particular it manages the Main-Class and Start-Class entries, so if the defaults don't work you have to configure those there (not in the jar plugin). The Main-Class in the manifest is actually controlled by the layout property of the boot plugin

[SpringBoot Maven-plugin-not-creating-executable-jar](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/usage.html)

Below changes as per SpringBoot docs worked for me.

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>YourSpringBootJavaClass</mainClass>
                <layout>WAR</layout>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>yourwarfileName</finalName>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had been building a runnable JAR (Maven POM) for a project for over a year and recently something changed and the JAR no longer contained any dependency JARs. Eventually, updating to latest Spring boot release (1.5.2.RELEASE for me at the time of writing) resolved the issue.