# no main manifest attribute maven build even after adding class path and main class

Tags: java, maven, build, maven-plugin, spring-boot-maven-plugin

[image: below i have added the snapshot of jar explode]I am facing a error while running application jar no main manifest attribute, in jaspr2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar.

In all the answers I find  that add class path and main class should be mentioned. In my POM i have mentioned both. After the build I find Manifest file is not appended with main class and also Boot/INF is not added in the jar. Looking for a solution to build proper jar. Below is my POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.abn</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaspr2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>jaspr2</name>
    <description>Project for jcl validation</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <antlr.version>4.8-1</antlr.version>
        <targetDirectory>target</targetDirectory>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId> 
            <scope>runtime</scope> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-decisiontables</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr4-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>${antlr.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.antlr/antlr4-maven-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr4-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${antlr.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr4</artifactId>
            <version>${antlr.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr4-master</artifactId>
            <version>${antlr.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <!-- <finalName>jaspr-application</finalName> -->
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
                    <artifactId>antlr4-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${antlr.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src</sourceDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>antlr4</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${mojo.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>add-source</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <sources>
                                    <source>${basedir}/src/main/java/com/abn/jaspr/antlr/generated</source>
                                </sources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>com.abn.jaspr.Jaspr2Application</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>repackage</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <jvmArguments>-Dfile.encoding=UTF8</jvmArguments>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Could you let us know the maven command used to build your jar?

Comment: maven clean and maven install using eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since spring-boot-maven-plugin inside the plugin management it was not executing and adding spring boot INF folder.
Just moved spring-boot-maven-plugin outside plugin management tag and it resolves the issue.

Find more details in this answer from other question
[Spring Boot Maven Plugin not creating executable jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26314374/spring-boot-maven-plugin-not-creating-executable-jar)

Answer (score 3):

For spring boot you can define main class using start class in properties.

below is your updated properties

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <antlr.version>4.8-1</antlr.version>
    <targetDirectory>target</targetDirectory>
    <start-class>com.abn.jaspr.Jaspr2Application</start-class>
</properties>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I tried updating plugin as you mentioned. Still find the same issue.

Comment: Did u try maven-jar-plugin & adding start-class properties?

Comment: yes I added both. What i observe is dependency jar is not packaged and bootinf is also not added

Comment: Adding start-class property alone is enough for spring boot to update Main-Class in manifest. i tried with your POM plugins used, it worked for me.

Comment: For me also its working for diffrent porjects with same plugins. For this particular project the dependency and sprig boot inf is not added in jar. Unable to identify the actual issue.